# Does $X_t\geq 0$, $\underset{t \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\mathbb{E}[X_t]=0$ imply $X_t \overset{a.s.}{\to} 0$?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider a non-negative stochastic process $X_t$ defined on probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Assume we have

\begin{align}
\underset{t \rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\mathbb{E}[X_t]=0
\end{align}

Does this imply $X_t \overset{a.s.}{\to} 0$?

Fatou's lemma implies that if $X_t$ converges almost surely, it must converge to zero. ([Connections between almost sure convergence and convergence in mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307946/connections-between-almost-sure-convergence-and-convergence-in-mean)) Moreover, a zero mean non-negative random variable is almost surely zero. ([A nonnegative random variable has zero expectation if and only if it is zero almost surely](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897876/a-nonnegative-random-variable-has-zero-expectation-if-and-only-if-it-is-zero-alm)) However, I am not sure how to handle this question.

Comment: with the assumption of non-negativity, your question reduces to (a special case of) "Does $L^1$ convergence imply convergence a.s.?" See here for a counter-example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/does-convergence-in-lp-implies-convergence-almost-everywhere

Comment: @nobody Do these counterexamples extend to my case? Looks a bit like that.

Comment: Yes. (up to a trivial adaptation if you want a continuous time process)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a sequence of independent r.v.s. $\{X_t\}_{t\in \mathbb{N}}$ s.t.
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_t=\sqrt{t})=t^{-1} \quad\text{and}\quad \mathsf{P}(X_t=0)=1-t^{-1}.
$$
Then
$$
\mathsf{E}X_t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\to 0 \quad\text{as }t\to\infty.
$$
However, $\mathsf{P}(X_t\ge 1 \text{ i.o.})=1$.

Comment: What does i.o. mean?

Comment: "infinitely often".

Comment: Why $\mathbb P (X_t \geq 1 \text{ i.o.}) = 1$?

Comment: Ah, Borel-Cantelli. Nevermind.